# How to get process stack size from kernel mod

Tags: c++, memory, kernel

I'm developing a kernel mod driver and I need to get all the stack sizes of some process.

I use `ZwQuerySystemInformation` to find the process
and then I use `ZwQuerySystemInformation` to get the `THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION`
and then I read memory from `TebBaseAddress` to `NT_TIB` struct
then I have the `tib.StackLimit`, `tib.StackBase`

```
if (NT_SUCCESS(PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)process_id, &process))) {
        if (NT_SUCCESS(MmCpy(process, (PVOID)info.TebBaseAddress, PsGetCurrentProcess(), &tib, sizeof(NT_TIB)))) {
            //DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "StackLimit: %#010x to StackBase: %#010x \n", tib.StackLimit, tib.StackBase);

            tempStackArea = { 0 };
            tempStackArea.Base = (uintptr_t)tib.StackBase;
            tempStackArea.Limit = (uintptr_t)tib.StackLimit;
            memcpy((PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)StackAreaList + (i * sizeof(StackArea))), &tempStackArea, sizeof(StackArea));
        }
    }
```

but I don't know if the size is

```
tib.StackBase - tib.StackLimit
```

I want to read all the stack memory from `tib.StackLimit` to `tib.StackBase` and search some value
Is it okay to use it this way or it's wrong, and there's another solution?

Comment: What are you trying to solve by searching the stack for this specific value? What is this specific value? How is it initialized? What is its purpose?

Comment: i try to develop application for scan all memory of some runing process.
i have all the static memory and all the virtual memory.
now i need to complite the stack memory and the heap memory.

i want to search player health value 100
so you can help me how to get the stack size of some process??

Comment: yes the MmCpy is MmCopyVirtualMemory

Comment: The player health will not be on the stack. This is pointless.

Comment: ok but other values will be there so i need this becuse i develop application to scan all the memory from process in the computer.

Comment: Use the well-documented API NtQueryVirtualMemory. It does precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: i use this API but the Nt its only for kernel mod process the Zw is for user mod process

Comment: Both Zw and NtQueryVirtualMemory may be used on any usermode process.

Comment: ok but the problem is not NtQueryVirtualMemory or Zw. (they will work with same struct only 2 letter to chenge)
how i get the stack size hhhh??

Comment: You don't have to get the stack size, because you can instead read all the memory of a process with the XXQueryVirtualMemory API.

Comment: Okay I already have all the virtual memory of process with this QueryVirtualMemory.
but its not cover stack memory.
or i wrong?

Comment: It does cover stack memory.

Comment: when i look on the address i get from the virtual memory and from the stack i compare the address but sory man the virtual memory not cover the stack address

Comment: You have to call NtQueryVirtualMemory several times.